# API Connect - making asynchronous backend calls

Tags: asynchronous, aggregate, apiconnect

I am trying the following scenario -
Build a Get products API in API Connect, which will invoke multiple back-end micro APIs and Web Services like product info, inventory, image lists, product reviews etc., and aggregate the response.
Is there a way to make these calls in parallel (asynchronously), to reduce overall latency?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the LoopBack Framework, which is also part of API Connect. 
This use case has been discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/39VI8apSsPM